# message box design for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, messagebox

I need to create a message box for user login system. Now I have users that can login and do many functionality.

The user table is something like this"

```
+-----+------+--------+
| uid | name | family |
+-----+------+--------+
```

Now I need too create a message box which will show users messages. They can view what they sent or what they recieve.

I can create table like this:

```
+-----------+-----+-------------+------+
| messageid | uid | messagetext | type |
+-----------+-----+-------------+------+
```

`messageid` is auto incremented and integer type and `type` is a boolean variable and, if it is 0, the message is in recieve box. If it's 1 - the message is in sent box, but where is the problem in my case?

I think, if we have autoincrement for this `messageid` field, this messageid will have very big number in future. For this reason I think this design might be wrong... is there any better solution for my users message box?

Comment: you need not be concerned abut the auto incremented value getting large.  Are you seeing any particular problem?  Seems like a fine, if simple solution.

Comment: It won't matter how big the numbers get, if you're using an int field you'll only run out of numbers when you pass 2 billion or 4 billion unsigned.

Comment: its the best idea with autoincrement value

Comment: ok then auto increment value wont be a problem in future?

Comment: No auto increment is pretty much the best way to organise rows in this case- anything from 0-4294967295 will only consume 4 bytes of information per number technically ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For message it would be like: 
If it's user to user interaction then:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+
| messageid | sender_uid | receiver_uid | messagetext | message_time | type |
+-----------+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+------+
```

Otherwise structure is good.

There wont be any problem due to large number of messageid. take appropriate datatype.

Comment: is messageid auto increment?

Comment: Are you referring that message id anywhere else ?

Comment: You should take it auto increment... It will be good for accessing messages as well. If you haven't taken it then you need to insert manually every time you insert message in daatabase